# TypeError when trying to pass string in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I'm trying to pass a tuple after an if statement in a for loop. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
procs = ((1432, 'var', 'var2', procname),(1556, 'var4', 'var5', othername),) 

def killprocs(procname):
    print "searching for %s" % procname      
    for i in procs:
        if procname in i[3]:
            print "proc %s matches." % i
        else:
            pass
```

I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "processkiller.py", line 59, in <module>
    killprocs(args.procname)
  File "processkiller.py", line 24, in killprocs
    print "proc %s matches." % i
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`str.__mod__()` is detecting that the right-hand operand is a tuple and so is attempting to use all elements in the formatting. To fix this, create a 1-tuple containing the tuple instead.

```
print "proc %s matches." % (i,)
```